# How to iterate through all components of a panel except one

Tags: java, swing

I have a question about java / swing.
I have build an input form with some JTextFields and JComboBoxes.

And I have two Buttons. Save and Abort. 
If you click Save, I check all fields for inputs. So if you miss one field an error appears.

Which works fine.

On Abort I want two cases. First case is, if something in the field is changed a JOptionPane appears with the question "Do you really want to close? Data loss blabla".

But if no inputs are made, it should just close without this message.

To check if something is changed I have this:

```
   private boolean isFormularChanged() {
    boolean isChanged = false;
    for (Component c : WeinDatenPanel.getComponents()){
        if (!isChanged && c instanceof JTextField) {
            isChanged = !((JTextField) c).getText().isEmpty();
        } else if (!isChanged && c instanceof JComboBox) {
            isChanged = isComboBoxChanged;
        }
    }   
    return isChanged;
}
```

The problem is, that my first JTextField has a MaskFormatter and Placeholders. So the .getText().isEmpty() doesnt work for this field. And isChanged is always true because of this.

Can I somehow iterate trough all the fields without my MaskFormatter field? 
An ugly solution would be to do this by hand and check all my fields by hand execpt my first one. But maybe theres another, cleaner solution?

Comment: One of possible solution is creating custom class extends JTextField and implements you interface (Changeable) with method `boolean isChanged()`. So you can include logic of changed in specific class

Comment: Things like an `InputVerifer` or `DocumentListener` might provide for a better solution. Take a look at [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for some more ideas

Comment: All `Components` has a get/setName. Maybe you can setName("N") and then check back with getName().equals("N").

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah I know. I am using an InputVerifier for the MaskFormatter. But its not about verifying, its about checking if a field is changed / or an input is made. Not matter if its a valid or invalid input. 

My problem is about useability, if no input is made and nothing changed I want the frame to close instantly. But if you made some changes, I want the confirmation dialog to appear.

Comment: Then maintain a model, which is updated by the `InputVertifer`s indicating if the field has been verified or not.  If it has been verified, then it has been changed.  No need to walk the component hierarchy or duplicate functionality...